# android local webview OnPageFinished firing late

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview which loads a local html page and I need to know when it has finished loading so I was using the function onPageFinished() which is fired straight away but for some reason it works fine on websites e.g. google.co.uk.

```
public class TestwebviewActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
WebView webview = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    Log.d("Webview", "created");
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
    { 
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
        { 
            Log.d("Webview", "Finished Loading");

            Picture picture = view.capturePicture(); 
            Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( 300, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
            Canvas c = new Canvas( b ); 
            picture.draw( c ); 
            FileOutputStream fos = null; 
            try { 
                fos = new FileOutputStream( "/sdcard/google_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg" ); 
                if ( fos != null ) 
                { 
                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos ); 
                    fos.close();
                    Log.d("Webview", "Image Created");
                } 
            } catch( Exception e ) 
            { 
            //... 
            } 
        } 
    });   
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/htmlpage.html");
}
```

}

This has only happened since upgraded to android 3.2 - previously on 2.3

Anyone come across the same issues or any suggestions?

Thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: I Have this problem as well, no one seem to provide answer for it, not even with a 100 bounty!

Comment: See if this solves it... we have just came up with it: http://android-know-how-to.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/android-webview-javascript-onpagefinish.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use deprecated `PictureListener`:

```
    wv.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
            if (i < pageList.size()) {
                wv.loadUrl("javascript: highlightSearchTerms('" + searchKey + "');");   
            } else listener.onFinishSearch();

            i++;
        }
    });
```